# Count occurrences with grep

Tags: linux, grep

grep -o "$var" file | wc -l

It works when I replace the "$var" with a text string, but not with the variable.

I have checked the the "$var" is a string.

grep -o "$var" file | wc -l

It works when I replace the "$var" with a text string, but not with the variable.

I have checked the the "$var" is a string.

**New:**

Hi, here is code.
The list.txt contain multi-line word list, each line contains one word.
The source.txt is a one line file which consist multiple characters without any spaces.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(seq 1 100)

do
word=$(sed "$i"'q;d' list.txt)
#remove the new line character
word=${word//$'\r\n'/}


grep -o "$word" source.txt | wc -l >>output


done
```

Example list.txt:

```
aa
bb
cc
```

Example source.txt:

```
aaccddffzzaabbhh
```

Comment: Use grep's -c flag, you don't need to pipe it through wc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you show should work as expected. How does it fail?

In any case, a better way to count the occurrences of each of a list of words in anoter file would be:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read word
do
    grep -oc "$word" source.txt >> output
done < <(sed 's/\r//' list.txt)
```

Here, I am using the `while` loop to read the file after removing windows style line endings. Then, I use grep's `-c` option to count the occurrences. When run on your example files, this produces:

```
$ cat output 
1
1
1
```

To count multiple occurrences in a single line, you could try this:

```
while read word
do 
    export word; 
    perl -lne '@c=/$ENV{"word"}/g; $f=scalar @c; print $f if $f>0' source.txt 
done < list.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! but the list file contains very long string, not words. So the grep -c didn't work but grep-o does.

Comment: @Wei I don't understand. The length of the string is irrelevant, this solution just reads each line of `list.txt` as `$word`. That's exactly what your `sed` was doing.  Please [edit] your question and add an example of the input. Whenever you ask a question here, _always_ provide us with an example we can reproduce. Otherwise, we will waste our time and yours offering solutions that don't work.

Comment: Sorry @terdon@terdon
Sorry.
Example attached.

list.txt
aa
bb
cc

source. txt
aaccddffzzaabbhh

Comment: Thanks @terdon There are 2 "aa" in the source file, should it counted as 2? Besides, the list is very long, I am thinking split it into several smaller tasks. Is it easier to use for loop rather than the for loop?

Comment: @Wei no, but the new version does. While loops are generally safer 'case they deal with spaces better. Not much of an issue here, you can use either. A `for` would require an extra process (`cat`) though, so I don't see why.

Comment: Looks like perl is a better solution. It is much faster than grep. However, the output from perl contains an additional line with 0 for each result, can you have a look?

Comment: @wei here you go. Now it only prints numbers > 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your issues must be in the way you are assigning the string to `var` to begin with. The form of your `grep` expression, including the variable is fine. Presuming you have `PATH` in `.bashrc` -- if not assign something you that matches to `i`). Try:

```
i=PATH; grep -o "$i" ~/.bashrc | wc -l
```

**output:**

```
5
```

Which is easily confirmed with:

```
$ i=PATH; grep "$i" ~/.bashrc
export PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
#  PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/festival/ ;export PATH
```

That's `5`. Post how you are assigning the value to `var` if you are still having issues.

Comment: Hi, here is code.
The list.txt contain multi-line word list, each line contains one word.
The source.txt is a one line file which consist multiple characters without any spaces.

#!/bin/bash

for i in $(seq 1 100)

do
word=$(sed "$i"'q;d' list.txt)
#remove the new line character
word=${word//$'\r\n'/}


grep -o "$word" source.txt | wc -l >>output


done